# Interact with a Docker server from Flutter app for authenticating

Tags: flutter, docker, dart, authentication

I have created a server on Docker, and I'm able to perform queries from Postman, for example a POST at localhost:8000/api/sign-in/ with body containing:

```
{
       "email": "john.doe1@example.com",
       "password": "tfX7WgBpkSCu"
}
```

How can I replicate this query on flutter app?
Currently I tried this code but didn't work:

```
final email = emailController.text.trim();
final password = passwordController.text.trim();

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/sign-in/';

try {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(apiUrl),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: jsonEncode({
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Successful login
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final user = data['user'];
    final token = data['token'];

    // Now you can use the 'user' and 'token' as needed
    print('Logged in user: $user');
    print('Token: $token');

    // Navigate to the next screen or perform other actions
  } else {
    // Failed login
    print('Failed to login. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');

    // Handle the error, show a message, etc.
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Handle any exceptions
  print('Error during login: $e');
}
```

I get the error:

> SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a few months ago.

If your server is running locally and you are using the Android emulator, you should try to switch **10.0.2.2:8000** as your server end-point instead of **localhost:8000**, as AVD uses 10.0.2.2 as an alias to the localhost interface.